# Multiple divs autoscrolling one after another with fixed title/header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML page with multiple divs. Each div having a section of its own. My requirement is to load the page initially with all the sections. Then to autoscroll the page so that the first div section has its header fixed and contents scrolling. At the end of its contents the second sections header takes up first section headers place and now contents for section 2 scrolls. Then the third sections header takes place of second header and contents for section 3 auto scrolls and so on. At the end of all section it again starts with section 1. Can anybody help me as to how to accomplish this?

Below is my code link,
http://pastebin.com/EAYtsWAT

I am using jsscroller for automatic content scrolling. I am able to scroll the contents but I dont know how to Keep header Activity1 fixed than scroll its contents, then remove that header and replace it with Activity2 header, scroll its contents and so on.

Comment: sure you can get help. Where is your code with what you have tried up to now and where exactly lies your problem?

Comment: I have added link to my code.

Comment: how will I make the header static and contents scrolling?

Comment: You need to post your problem code as well as including the link to pastebine: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle

Comment: Actually I pasted the code that I had so far working. There isnt any particular problem code, as I am not sure how to add the functionality of scrolling divs while keeping headers constant as mentioned above. The code in pastebin, scrolls the entire page loaded with all the divs along with the headers. I want the header to be fixed and scroll content of each div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some housekeeping on the code that you provided (and moving it [to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/VE4sU/12/)) here's something that (I think) does what you want.

The jscroller functionality is relatively limited, so I had to apply some tweaks to get it together:

```
function SectionManager(){
    this.currentSection = null;
    this.sections = $("#content .section");
    this.numSections = this.sections.length;

    this.transition = function (current){
            //SCROLLER CODE STARTS HERE....
             $jScroller.config.refresh = 100;
            // Add Scroller Object
            $jScroller.config.obj = [];
            $jScroller.add(
                "#content .section.active .activityTbl",
                "#content .section.active .activityTbl > table",
                "up",
                3
            );
            // Start Autoscroller
            $jScroller.start();
            $jScroller.cache.init = true;
            //SCROLLER CODE ENDS HERE....
    };
    this.callback = function (){
        this.currentSection = (this.currentSection != null)
            ? (this.currentSection + 1) % this.numSections
            : 0
        ;
        $("#content .section").removeClass("active");
        $("#content .section:eq(" + this.currentSection + ")").addClass("active");
        this.transition();
    }

    this.run = function(){
        this.callback();
    };

}

manager = new SectionManager();
manager.run();
```

Notably also, I had to overwrite the $jScroller.scroll function to contain an asynchronous callback to fire when the end is reached: This will trigger the manager's callback function and shift the scrolling functionality to the next section.

**Edit:** See the [**jsfiddle for details**](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/VE4sU/12/)

Comment: thank you so much for your help. Is there a way to refresh the page every time it goes to a next section or refresh it at the end of the last section before it goes to the first section. That way we can have the most updated contents from the server.

Comment: Also is it possible to pause the section for 15 seconds if content items are less than 12 else scroll them like it does now. I really appreciate your help with this. Let me know if this is not possible or requires a lot of work. The reason I am asking is if activities are like 1 or 2 it just scrolls and if someone is not paying attention they might just lose it.

Comment: yes, I think that is possible. Let me check and get back to you.

Comment: I've edited the answer with a link to a new jsfiddle. Note: In the jsfiddle, the "window.location.replace()" command is commented because jsfiddle itself restricts page reloads - when you move this to your site, just uncomment that line of code.

Comment: Thanks marty. I checked it and after a couple of rounds of all sections(like 3 or 4) the activities that are less than 12,stop for only 2-3 seconds instead of 15. Can you please check that. Again thank you so much for all your help so far.

Comment: this.delayShortList = 15000; means the delay is configured as 15000 ms == 15 seconds. 
My suspicion is that you fell victim to a 'feature' of the jscroller plugin: When you ***move your mouse*** over the scollable section, scrolling will start (no matter what delay has been coded).

Comment: Yes marty. I think you are right. Whenever I move my mouse or click in that area the scrolling starts. I dont know why that happens because the documentation at http://jscroller.markusbordihn.de/docs/ says that if I do not put a true as one of the parameters ( $jScroller.add("#box1_container","#box1","down",1,true);), it will not respond to mouseover mouseout event.

Comment: I appreciate all your help with this. I am going to mark this as an answer and also upvote it. If you have a solution to the above mouse event can you please let me know. Thanks a lot again for your help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/VE4sU/15/
 is another update. I've overridden the 'start' method to get rid of all the funky mouse stuff. Hope that this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could use [Scrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/). You can pin and unpin stuff depending on scroll, while other elements (content) scroll normally.